# how to copy UV Maps?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, armature, texture-baking

So I have a UV map on one mesh and want it to be the exact same as the other, how would I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe unwrap all these faces at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

If your objects are the same, you can link object data, so that objects will share the same UV sets. To do that, select objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> → object data. (object with correct UV have to be selected last to be active). In this case, objects will share not only UV maps, but also all geometry data.

If your objects are similar (have the same topology) you can use Transfer UV maps. Press <kbd>F3</kbd> ant type Transfer UV maps:

[image]

It will copy UV's from the active object to all selected objects.

If objects have some differences in structure, you can use **data transfer** modifier:

[image]

Note that object transform should be disabled, because objects are in the different positions.

Once modifier is set, you can apply it to view results in UV editor.